# How to require module from parent folder in Node/Express JS?

Tags: node.js, express

```
-controller
---user_controller.js

-router
---user
------user_router.js
```

I have a file structure as above in my Express Js project, but I am facing difficulties to require user_controller from user_router. The only way I can required that is by using this method :

```
const user_controller = require(process.mainModule.path + '/controller/user_controller')
```

But something tells me that this might not be the best practice to do so. Anyone hove any idea to do so?

Comment: You can use relative paths just fine: `require('./../../controller/user_controller')`

Comment: Gosh. It just worked ! I feel so sorry for such silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require('./../../controller/user_controller')` do solved the problem. Sorry for being silly, and Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const user_controller = require('../controller/user_controller);
```

Comment: Nope. This doesn't work. Anyway, I had tried the method provided by @m90 and it does solved my problem. Thanks thou.

Comment: Ok, you just had to adjust the path :)